# How to prevent duplicate item in listview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I want to add an item to a ListView when a button is clicked and I want to add the quantity. I keep getting an error saying

> Cannot add or insert the item 'Burger' in more than one place. You must first remove it from its current location or clone it.

Here's my code so far:

```
For Each listItem As ListViewItem In lvOrder.Items
    If Not lvOrder.Items.ContainsKey("Burger") Then

        listItem.Text = "Burger"
        listItem.SubItems.Add(1) 'Quantity
        listItem.SubItems.Add(50.0) 'Price

        lvOrder.Items.Add(listItem)
     Else
        MessageBox.Show("Item already exist")
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add more than one item with the same Name (key) to a ListView. But, I think what you are actually trying to do is *edit* an existing item.

You can simplify your code a lot. Add items like:

```
Dim newListItem As New ListViewItem
newListItem.Text = "Burger"
newListItem.Name = "Burger" ' this is a unique key
lvOrder.Items.Add(newListItem)
```

Notice that Text and Name are different properties. Text is what is displayed to the user, and Name is a key that helps the ListView keep track of what items have been added. It can be the same as Text, or something totally different.

If you need to modify an item you've already added, it's as easy as looking it up with the key!

```
lvOrder.Items.Item("Burger").SubItems.Add(1) ' Quantity
lvOrder.Items.Item("Burger").SubItems.Add(50.0) ' Price
```

No need to loop through every item to find the one you're looking for!

Comment: thank you for replying to this question. it's working fine now.

Comment: @JarobeBernardo Great! Happy to help. :) If this completely answered your question, you can click the checkmark to accept it as an answer.